# Reynould equation and partial answer

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been working on solving an ODE equation in trying to find the pressure gradient along a hydrostatic bearing, as far as literature goes,

the given ode 
$\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(\frac{h^3}{12 \eta 
    }\text{}r\text{ }\frac{\partial p}{\partial r}\right)=0$
with a simply given solution of;

$p(r)\text{:=}\frac{\text{pt} (\log (r)-\log (R))}{\log (\delta )-\log (R)}$
With $p(\delta )=\text{pt},\text{ }p(R)=0$ as the Initial values.

For me, it seems to look like a simple double integrated ode
$\frac{\partial ^2p}{\partial r^2}=\text{ }0$
, with a solution of:

$p(r)\to \frac{\text{pt} R-\text{pt} r}{R-\delta }$

and infact, when evaluating with mathematica, I get the same answer as by hand.

My solution is a very simply linear one...and since I'm dealing with typically non-linear systems I can't imagine it's as simple as I have solved it.

So, to ask the question, how did they get their answer?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. The given ODE is indeed linear, assuming $h$ and $\eta$ are constants. Your simplified ODE is a common approach people take to understand difficult equations (typically more applied in PDE's) by considering the highest order derivative term.

Comment: ahh, yes you're right the ode is linear...Ahhh i meant the solution i have...is quite literally a straight line when plotted...the pressure gradient in a hydrostatic bearing should drop as one approaches the edges non linearly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(\frac{h^3}{12 \eta 
    }\text{}r\text{ }\frac{\partial p}{\partial r}\right)=0$$
Integrating once with respect to $r$ we get
$$\frac{h^3}{12\eta}\frac{\partial{p}}{\partial{r}}=\frac{c_{1}}{r}$$
for some constant $c_{1}$. Integrating the second time, 
$$\frac{h^3}{12\eta}p(r)=c_{1}\ln{(r)}+c_{2}$$
or, using $A=\frac{12c_{1}\eta}{h^{3}}$ and $B=\frac{12c_{2}\eta}{h^{3}}$
$$p(r)=A\ln{r}+B$$
using the boundary conditions we have
$$B=-A\ln{R}$$
$$A=\frac{pt}{\ln{\delta}-\ln{R}}$$

Comment: Ahh so that's how...thanks! But why not factor in d/dr first then simplify h^3/12eta before integrating ?...or is that against order of operations ?

Comment: Yeh, $\frac{h^3}{12\eta}$ commutes with $\frac{d}{dr}$, thus, as long as it is not zero you can divide it out.